# How to enter text using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

This is what I have in devtools:

Your name

This is my variant

```
    By fieldNameYourNamePath = By.;
    WebElement fieldNameYourName = driver.findElement(fieldNameYourNamePath);
    fieldNameYourName.sendKeys("Test");
```

Comment: <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" name="name" required="">
<div pseudo="-webkit-input-placeholder" id="placeholder" style="display: block !important;">Your name</div>
</input>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys("value");
```